# Understanding React Natives setState and componentWillMount from FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

So I'm trying to make a simple application with expo and expo audio that will generate a list of audio buttons and text. But I cannot figure out how react works regarding redrawing the setState OUTSIDE componentWillMount and how to remake a soundobject with a new URI

So right now it will work but only playing the FIRST uri, I assume this is because the object still exists.

And it will not change the state of the button, I know this is because react cant see its changing for some reason from FlatList

It works outside of it, if I only make one button in renders view.

FlatList will render the setStates if I use LegacyImplementation=true .. But Im warned this is deprecated. And it renders it for all buttons at the same time

This is my handlerClass:

```
export class TSSGetter extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ 
      isLoading: true,
      playingStatus: "Play"
    }
  }



  retrieveData() {
    const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:3333/get'

    const data = {
        "userId": "123412341234",
        "hmac": "detteerikkeenrigtighmac"
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(endpoint, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-type':'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then((resp) => {
          console.log('hej return')
            return resp.json();

        })
        .then((resp) => {
            resolve(resp);
            console.log('resp')
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error,'naeh')
        });
    });
}

  componentDidMount(){


     this.retrieveData()
     .then((resp) => {
        var pages = resp.books.contentObjects

        pages.map((userData) => {
          console.log('superduper pages', userData.contentObjectId)

        })
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: resp.books.contentObjects,
            dataroot: resp.books

        });

    }).catch((err) => {
        //handle error

        console.log("Api call error2");
     alert(err);
    })
  }

  async _playRecording(AudioURL) {
    console.log(AudioURL)
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      {uri: AudioURL},
      {
        shouldPlay: true,
        isLooping: true,
      },
      this._updateScreenForSoundStatus,
    );
    this.sound = sound;
    this.setState({
      playingStatus: 'playing'
    });
  }

  _updateScreenForSoundStatus = (status) => {
    if (status.isPlaying && this.state.playingStatus !== "playing") {
      this.setState({ playingStatus: "playing" });
    } else if (!status.isPlaying && this.state.playingStatus === "playing") {
      this.setState({ playingStatus: "donepause" });
    }
  };

  async _pauseAndPlayRecording() {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      if (this.state.playingStatus == 'playing') {
        console.log('pausing...');
        await this.sound.pauseAsync();
        console.log('paused!');
        this.setState({
          playingStatus: 'donepause',
        });
      } else {
        console.log('playing...');
        await this.sound.playAsync();
        console.log('playing!');
        this.setState({
          playingStatus: 'playing',
        });
      }
    }
  }

  _syncPauseAndPlayRecording() {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      if (this.state.playingStatus == 'playing') {
        this.sound.pauseAsync();
      } else {
        this.sound.playAsync();
      }
    }
  }

  _playAndPause = (AudioURL) => {
    console.log(AudioURL)
    switch (this.state.playingStatus) {
      case 'Play':
        this._playRecording(AudioURL);
        break;
      case 'donepause':
      case 'playing':
        this._pauseAndPlayRecording();
        break;
    }
  }

  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }
    const styling = {
      flex: 1, 
      paddingTop:10
      // flexDirection: 'row'
    }
    const data = this.state.dataroot;
    return(

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <FlatList

          data={this.state.dataSource}

          renderItem={({item}) => 
          <View>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this._playAndPause(item.AudioURL)}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                {this.state.playingStatus}+ {item.contentObjectId}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.description}>
          {item.text}, 

          </Text>
          </View>

          }
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.contentObjectId}

        />
      </View>
    );

  }
}
```

UPDATE: setting extraData={this.state} in flatlist updates the button.. But all the buttons. How do I change the scope of the button?

Comment: You mean to say each row should behave independently i.e pause, playing should be independent for each item in the `FlatList`?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a specific component for the items in the `FlatList`. Each of the items will then have their own state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Sound />}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Sound extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      status: "IDLE"
    };
  }

  onChangeState = value => {
    this.setState({
      status: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { status } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{width: 200,paddingVertical: 10}}>
        <Text>Status: {status}</Text>
        <View style={{ flex: 1,flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
          <Text onPress={() => this.onChangeState("PLAYING")}>PLAY</Text>
          <Text onPress={() => this.onChangeState("STOPPED")}>STOP</Text>
          <Text onPress={() => this.onChangeState("PAUSED")}>PAUSE</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 100,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

[image: sound]

Answer (score 0):

I checked out in the docs, [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist), and I saw that it will re-render just if you pass the state prop, see this explanations:

> By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

Comment: Yep, found this too and added extraData, but it updates all my buttons. This is where my comprehension stops, how do I update individuals here?

Comment: Well, it has to do with setState itself, when you call setState it will re-render the entire component, and will update just the props that were changed. if you want to update individuals (an item of the list), you have to set the state of the entire list, in your case "dataSource", this will trigger a re-render of the component.